# Loop and return each item individually

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, mpandroidchart

I am using [MpAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and trying to set custom labels using this method:

```
String[] daysOfTheWeek = {"M","T","W","T","F","S","S"};

XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();

xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() { //Returns a string not a list :(
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            int position = 0;
            for(int i =0; i<daysOfTheWeek.length;i++){
                position = i;
            }
            return daysOfTheWeek[position];
        }
    });
```

However I only get the last item of the array = **S**.

How can I return all the items individually?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
String[] daysOfTheWeek = {"M","T","W","T","F","S","S"};

XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();

int position = 0;
for(int i =0; i<daysOfTheWeek.length;i++){
       position = i;
       xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() { //Returns a string not a list :(
           @Override
           public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                return daysOfTheWeek[position];

           }

        }
})
```

Comment: That still returns the last item of the array

Comment: Use log inside getaFormaatedValue function and check the value of value

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, the method accepts a `float` `value`. I simply had to use it!

```java
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
        return daysOfTheWeek[(int)value];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the last item of array use this:

```
return daysOfTheWeek[daysOfTheWeek.length-1];
```

If you want to get items individually, you could create a method that gets position of item and return that item:

```
public String getItem(int position)
{
     return daysOfTheWeek[position];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();

    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getAreaCount));

    public ArrayList<String> getAreaCount() {

                ArrayList<String> label = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < areaList.size(); i++)
                    label.add(areaList.get(i).getTopicName());
                return label;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick works 100% for me to display week days from Mo to SU

```js
chartWeeklyDistance.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
  
   String[] daysOfTheWeek = {"MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU"};
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                if (((int) value) > -1 && ((int) value) < 7) {
                    return daysOfTheWeek[((int) value)];
                }
                return "";
            }
        });
```